# How to get data from two different tables with different field names

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the data from two different tables with different fields name like,

table 1

```
user_id  user_grp_id
1         1
2         1
```

table 2

```
cust_id cust_grp_id
1       2
2       2
```

Now Iam using a query like this

```
Select * from table 1 Union All select * from table 2
```

It is showing the result like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
     [user_id] => 1
     [user_grp_id] => 1
)

[1] => Array
    (
    [user_id] => 2
    [user_grp_id] => 1
)
[2] => Array
    (
     [user_id] => 1
     [user_grp_id] => 2
)

[3] => Array
    (
    [user_id] => 2
    [user_grp_id] => 2
)
```

Now as we can see the result from the second table also come under the field name of the first table but I want the result like this.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
     [user_id] => 1
     [user_grp_id] => 1
)

[1] => Array
    (
    [user_id] => 2
    [user_grp_id] => 1
)
[2] => Array
    (
     [cust_id] => 1
     [cust_grp_id] => 2
)

[3] => Array
    (
    [cust_id] => 2
    [cust_grp_id] => 2
)
```

How can I achieve this kind of results.

**EDIT**

The result for the query given in the answer is

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
     [user_id] => 1
     [user_grp_id] => 1
     [cust_id] => NULL
     [cust_grp_id] => NULL
)

[1] => Array
    (
    [user_id] => 2
    [user_grp_id] => 1
    [cust_id] => NULL
    [cust_grp_id] => NULL
)
[2] => Array
    (
     [user_id] => NULL
     [user_grp_id] => NULL
     [cust_id] => 1
     [cust_grp_id] => 2
)

[3] => Array
    (
    [user_id] => NULL
    [user_grp_id] => NULL
    [cust_id] => 2
    [cust_grp_id] => 2
)
```

Comment: did you got answer or not..

Comment: No I didn't got the answer yet.

Comment: did you see this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/786795/4

Comment: yeah I see it and yeah it give me the answer but with two extra field ie the fields with the null value.

Comment: if you dont mine clearly display the result pls..

Comment: @jmail I updated the question with my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have different fields that have different names you shouldn't return them in the same position. You can use null value to fill the empty slots.
So you can do something like this:

```
SELECT user_id, user_grp_id, NULL AS cust_id, NULL AS cust_grp_id FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL AS user_id, NULL AS user_grp_id, cust_id, cust_grp_id FROM table2
```

sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/786795/4)

Comment: sorry to say but it is not showing the result what I want, the first two arrays are same as of my results in the question but the second two array shows the null value with the same field name ie `user_id` and `user_grp_id`

Comment: what's the problem if those fields' value is `null`? just ignore them

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon I dont know what is the problem I tried this way but nothing happen

Comment: can you be more specific? *what* didn't happen?

Comment: @rikpg I can get that result with two queries, but i want to know how can i get this with one single query

Comment: **@rikpg, if you don't mine so me final result in sqlfiddle pls...**

Comment: **@rikpg, this too wrong, show me the final result in the sqlfiddle pls, like your query..**

Comment: ok.. I tried your edited query, and yes it works but with the two extra fields in each array, ie the fields with null value.

Comment: and you can't ignore them?